# How to analyze ODE equilibrium stability with complex equilibria

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, dynamical-systems

Take this example: $y'=y^2+1$. There's no "real equilibrium", but is it right to say it has two "complex equilibria"? If so, what should be the conclusion of the derivative test?
$$y'' = 2y \implies 2i>0  \vee  2i<0?$$

Comment: It's always positive. So, there's no equilibrium. But, what if we start with a complex initial value? Is that possible in theory?

Comment: The slopes are all positive, no equilibrium is seen!

Comment: If $y'=F(y)$ for some real valued $F$ and some real valued initial condition $y(t_0)$, then $y(t)$ is real valued for every $t$ such that $y(t)$ exists hence the zeroes of $F$ that are not on the real axis are simply irrelevant.

Comment: $y''=2yy'=2(y^2+1)y$

Comment: Note that $\pm i$ are equilibria of the complex valued differential equation $$z'=z^2+1.$$ Using $z=x+iy$ with $(x,y)$ real valued, this single equation is equivalent to the 2D system $$x'=1+x^2-y^2\qquad y'=2xy$$ The system has two fixed points, namely, $(x,y)=(0,\pm1)$, which are both centers for the linearized system, since the change of variables $(x,y)=(u,\pm1+v)$ with $u=o(1)$ and $v=o(1)$ yields $$u'=\mp2v\qquad v'=\pm2u$$ at the first order, whose solutions are circles centered at $(0,\pm1)$. ...

Comment: ... It happens that these two equilibria are furthermore "true" topological centers since the system is reversible with involution $R:(x,y)\mapsto(−x,y)$ (remark due to @Evgeny).

Comment: Cool, but the exercise just asks to find all equilibria and determine their stability. Since nothing topological has appeared yet in class, I will assume that there are no equilibria. Is that fair?

Comment: Yes, for some real valued initial condition, there is no equilibrium.